# How to initialize data for flagged questions and bind it to repeater in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I am working on an Online Exam System. I have stucked in questions (Flagged) these are the questions which are marked by student to be attempted later. I have table named "Questionsflagged" in db. Let's suppose there is a  Now I want to initialize data for first question. Here is the code behind button of reviseflagged.

**aspx page**

Below is the code for repeater.

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-1">
        <div class="col-sm-1 checkbox">
                <label>
                    <asp:CheckBox ToolTip="Mark as Flagged" ID="cbFlagged" 
    runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="cbFlagged_CheckedChanged" />
                </label>
                </div>

        <asp:Repeater ID="repeaterItems" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2" style="text-align:justify">
                            <asp:Label CssClass="question" id="lblQuestionNo" runat="server">Question # <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "SrNo") %></asp:Label>:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:Label ID="lblQuestionText" CssClass="question" runat="server"><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionText") %></asp:Label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <br />
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2">
                <asp:RadioButtonList CssClass="spaced" EnableViewState="true" ViewStateMode="Enabled" ID="rblOptions" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" OnSelectedIndexChanged="rblOptions_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Get Flagged**

```
protected void btnReviseFlagged_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
if (getFlaggedQuestions().Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            //CurrentPageNo = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString());
            //IncrementCount = int.Parse(dt.Rows[0]["Id"].ToString());

            lblCurrentPage.Visible = true;
            //var first record

            //NavigateRecords(dtQuestionFlagged);
            isFlagged = true;

            questionsFlagged = makeFlaggedData();

            IncrementCount = int.Parse(questionsFlagged.Rows[0]["SrNo"].ToString());
            CurrentPageNo = int.Parse(questionsFlagged.Rows[0]["SrNo"].ToString());
            var questionNo = repeaterItems.FindControl("lblQuestionNo") as Label;
            questionNo = new Label();
            questionNo.Text = questionsFlagged.Rows[0]["SrNo"].ToString();
            var questionText = repeaterItems.FindControl("lblQuestionText") as Label;
            questionText = new Label();
            questionText.Text = questionsFlagged.Rows[0]["QuestionText"].ToString();

            //build query for flagged
            var flaggedData = from qflagged in questionsFlagged.AsEnumerable()
                               where qflagged.Field<int>("SrNo") == int.Parse(questionNo.Text)
                               select new
                               {
                                   SrNo = qflagged.Field<int>("SrNo"),
                                   QuestionText = qflagged.Field<string>("QuestionText")
                               };
            repeaterItems.DataSource = flaggedData.AsEnumerable();
            repeaterItems.DataBind();
            Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            for (int j = 3; j < 7; j++)
            {
```

**Below is the line where I got error. I have marked question no. 5 as flagged but at this line compiler shows there is no row at position 5**

```
values.Add(questionsFlagged.Rows[IncrementCount][j].ToString(), questionsFlagged.Columns[j].ToString());

            }

            //var options = repeaterItemsFindControl("rblOptions") as RadioButtonList;
            //options = new RadioButtonList();

            rblOptions.DataSource = values;
            rblOptions.DataTextField = "Key";
            rblOptions.DataValueField = "Value";
            rblOptions.DataBind();
            lblCurrentPage.Text = CurrentPageNo.ToString();

            NavigateRecords(questionsFlagged);

        }
        else
        {
            isFlagged = false;
        }
}
```

**Normal Navigation on repeater with option to pass flagged questions**

```
public void NavigateRecords(DataTable dtFlaggedParameter)
    {
        PagedDataSource pds = new PagedDataSource();
        //IncrementCount+=1;
        //CurrentPageNo+=1;
        if (getFlaggedQuestions().Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            getFlaggedQuestions();
            cbFlagged.Checked = false;
        }

        if (isFlagged == true)
        {
            if (dtFlaggedParameter.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                pds.DataSource = dtFlaggedParameter.DefaultView;
                pds.AllowPaging = true;
                pds.PageSize = 1;

                // Set the PagedDataSource's current page

                pds.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPageNo;
                lblCurrentPage.Text = "Page No: " + (CurrentPageNo + 1).ToString() + " of "
                    + pds.PageCount.ToString();
                btnPrev.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
                //btnNext.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;
                btnFirst.Enabled = !pds.IsFirstPage;
                btnLast.Enabled = !pds.IsLastPage;
                //btnSubmit.Visible = pds.IsLastPage;

                repeaterItems.DataSource = pds;
                repeaterItems.DataBind();
                Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                for (int j = 3; j < 7; j++)
                {
                    values.Add(dtFlaggedParameter.Rows[IncrementCount] 
[j].ToString(), dtFlaggedParameter.Columns[j].ToString());
                }

                //var options = repeaterItemsFindControl("rblOptions") as 
RadioButtonList;
                //options = new RadioButtonList();

                rblOptions.DataSource = values;
                rblOptions.DataTextField = "Key";
                rblOptions.DataValueField = "Value";
                rblOptions.DataBind();
            }
        }
else{
      //same code as above but that datatable's name is dt

}
```

Comment: this is not winforms? is it?

Comment: @Igor thanks I have also added the webforms tag

Comment: @Igor Yes this is webforms instead of winforms